# MySQL Query doesn't work but works some time, whats wrong with it?

Tags: mysql

Below Query doesn't work most of the time and giving error Getting error `#1048 - Column 'StateStarttime' cannot be null` but work sometimes, what am I doing wrong here

I think `DATE_FORMAT( NOW()-60 , '%H:%i' )` causing the issue if it is what will be the right syntax?

```
INSERT INTO time ( 
EmpID, 
Date, 
Username, 
Computername, 
State, 
MinutesatState, 
StateStarttime, 
StateEndtime 
) VALUES ( 
'303016', 
CURDATE(), 
'yatendra', 
'NIPL885', 
'Active', 
'1', 
DATE_FORMAT( NOW()-60 , '%H:%i' ), 
DATE_FORMAT( NOW() , '%H:%i' ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOW()` in number context is treated as de-delimitered textual datetime in short format (see [Conversion Between Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html), the last demo). So substraction can cause invalid datetime value.

To obtain correct result perform calculations in datetime context. The best (and simplest) way is to use

```
NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND
```

or use some datetime function.